# Conditionally applying function using ddply

Tags: r, plyr

i'm looking to run ddply on a subsest of my data but the below example just returns TRUE or FALSE

`ddply(demoData, .(name, id, gender == "Male"), summarize, tot = sum(count))`

and

`ddply(demoData[demoData$gender == 'Male'], .(name, id, gender), summarize, tot = sum(count))`

doesn't seem to work either. 
ultimately i need to sum up "count" for all instances of gender = "Male" by name and id.

data sample as requested

```
id   name    gender     age      count
1    apple    Male      13-20      25
1    apple    Male      21-40      30
1    apple    Female    13-20      60
1    apple    Female    21-40      42
2    banana   Male      13-20      45
2    banana   Male      21-40      12
2    banana   Female    13-20      22
2    banana   Female    21-40      74
```

what i want to return is

```
1    apple    Male   55
2    banana   Male   57
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base R's `aggregate` can do this very simply:

```
aggregate(
          count ~ id + name + gender,
          FUN=sum, 
          subset=gender=="Male",
          data=demoData
         )
```

Result:

```
  id   name gender count
1  1  apple   Male    55
2  2 banana   Male    57
```

And if you absolutely must use `plyr` because your life depends on it or some other reason, then:

```
ddply(
   demoData[demoData$gender=="Male",],
   .(id, name, gender),
   summarise, 
   sumcount=sum(count)
  )
```

Giving:

```
  id   name gender sumcount
1  1  apple   Male       55
2  2 banana   Male       57
```

Comment: if you use `subset(demoData,gender=="Male")` (which I think it marginally nicer than this form of indexing, even if it very occasionally causes problems) I can go ahead and delete my answer ...

Comment: @BenBolker - I always avoid the `subset` function out of the mentioned fear of it causing unintended issues. Is it ok to change it in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Even though `ddply` doesn't have a built-in `subset` argument,

```
ddply(subset(demoData, gender=="Male"),
    .(name, id), summarize, tot = sum(count))
```

seems to work fine ...

```
    name id tot
1  apple  1  55
2 banana  2  57
```

...  although it doesn't have `Male` in the results.  For that you would need

```
ddply(subset(demoData, gender=="Male"),
    .(name, id, gender), summarize, tot = sum(count))
```